# Range.Replace in Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I try to replace some cells with `Range.Replace`, but when I try to do it, my program only change the first cell find it.

How I can do ?

```
range = sheet.UsedRange;
// leer las celdas
int rows = range.Rows.Count;
int cols = range.Columns.Count;

Excel.Range startCell = sheet.Cells[1, 1];
Excel.Range endCell = sheet.Cells[rows, cols];
sheet.Range[startCell, endCell].Replace(@"'C:\", @"'C:\Gestion\");
```

Now I try to do this:

```
// seleccion rango activo
range = sheet.UsedRange;
// leer las celdas
int rows = range.Rows.Count;
int cols = range.Columns.Count;

Excel.Range startCell = sheet.Cells[1, 1];
Excel.Range endCell = sheet.Cells[rows, cols];
sheet.Range[startCell, endCell].Replace(@"C:\", @"C:\Gestion\", Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, false, Type.Missing, false, false);
```

But I have the same problem, only change one cell in my sheet :S

Comment: Are you sure rows and/or cols are > 1?

Comment: Yes, the rows and cols are > 1 :S I don't find the error

Comment: Can you post a picture of the data? The second code seems correct.

Comment: I would advise adding the Excel file or a link to download it for easier trying to help

Comment: I tried your code, first example doesn't replace anything since `'` is a special symbol in Excel. Removing the `'`'s in the last line of the first example makes it replace `ALL` occurrences, not only the first one. I also tried the second example. It is replacing all occurrences too. Provide us with the example excel file and I will test that with your exact file.

Answer (score 4):

**Your code is correct.** Here are some things you could check:

(1) Are your search settings set to be case sensitive? If this is the problem, try replacing your code with this:

`sheet.Range[startCell, endCell].Replace(@"'C:\", @"'C:\Gestion\", matchcase: false);`

(2) You use the apostrophe (') in your search string. There are multibyte variants of this character - does your spreadsheet use these instead of actual apostrophes? (An apostrophe is character 39 in ASCII, or 27 in hexadecimal.)

(3) The apostrophe has a special meaning in Excel when used as the first character in a cell - it tells Excel that the cell contains text data. (Try entering `'1` in a cell instead of `1` to see the difference.) If you want a cell to start with an actual apostrophe, you'll need to double it up - so `''C:\` will be rendered as `'C:\` in the cell, and this is what will be searched (ignoring the first apostrophe).

My guess is that (3) is the most likely, but if none of the above suggestions work then it would help if you could provide some more information.

Comment: Well, I try this, but I can't fix it. Now I try again with: sheet.Range[startCell, endCell].Replace(@"C:\", @"C:\Gestion\"); Without apostrophe, but the problem still here. I want to search each cell excel contains this string "C:\", and after replace all of them for this C:\Gestion

Comment: Could you post the exact contents (formulas, not values) of the cell that is being correctly replaced and some of the cells that are not?

Answer (score 0):

I made this one to remove ' and it's working good:

```
            var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Workbook wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"c:\folder\excelfile.xlsx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            var ws = wb.Worksheets;
            var worksheet = (Worksheet)ws.get_Item("sheetname");

            Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;

            int rows = range.Rows.Count;
            int cols = range.Columns.Count;

            Range startCell = worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
            Range endCell = worksheet.Cells[rows, cols];

            worksheet.Range[startCell, endCell].Replace("'", "", MatchCase: false);


            wb.Close(true);
            excelApp.Quit();
```